# Add Drag/Stretch Text Sticker on a Image view

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-imageview

How to add a Text view on a Image view like a sticker which can be dragged around or stretched to zoom, like this?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using this github library

[TextSticker](https://github.com/wuapnjie/StickerView)

and here is the sample usage

In layout

```
<com.xiaopo.flying.sticker.StickerView
        android:id="@+id/sticker_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
    <!-- custom, maybe you will like to put an ImageView--> 
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/haizewang_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</com.xiaopo.flying.sticker.StickerView>
```

Add sticker
If the sticker is drawable, it's intrinsic width and height can not be zero. If the sticker is text, you can set text color, font and alignment and the region which holds the text.

```
stickerView.addSticker(sticker)
stickerView.replace(sticker)
stickerView.remove(sticker)
stickerView.removeCurrentSticker()
stickerView.removeAllStickers()
stcikerView.setLocked(true)
```

Also you can custom the icon and icon event and position

```
BitmapStickerIcon heartIcon =
        new BitmapStickerIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_favorite_white_24dp),
            BitmapStickerIcon.LEFT_BOTTOM);
heartIcon.setIconEvent(new HelloIconEvent());

stickerView.setIcons(Arrays.asList(deleteIcon, zoomIcon, flipIcon, heartIcon));
```